# can someone please tell me the syntax error in the code, its in the insert section

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert

```
Private Sub AddUser()
    ' ADD PARAMETERS
    Access.AddParam("@Title", TextBoxTitle.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@Urgency", TextBoxUrgent.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@Data", TextBoxData.Text)

    ' EXECUTE INSERT COMMAND
    Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Table (Title,Urgency,Data) " &
                     "VALUES (@Title,@Urgency,@Data); ")

    ' REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub

    ' SUCCESS!!
    MsgBox("User was added successfully.")

    Me.RefreshGrid()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what sort of syntax error, VB.NET or SQL? What was the error message? Also, how is the `Access` object defined?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Table` - replace `table` with the actual name of the table! Also data is a key word in SQL, so you may need to wrap it in square brackets. e.g. `(Title,Urgency,[Data])`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please remember, if your question only contains code it is hardly a question. Please edit and make it more clear what you need from us.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how your method might look like.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private Sub AddUser(title As String, urgency As String, data As String)
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Title,Urgency,Data)
                                        VALUES (@Title,@Urgency,@Data);", cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Title", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = title
            .Add("@Urgency", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = urgency
            .Add("@Data", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = data
        End With
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

To call the method...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        AddUser(TextBoxTitle.Text, TextBoxUrgent.Text, TextBoxData.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```